# Jquery Validate Plugin with confirm message

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and am using the JQuery validation plugin. The validation work fine but I want to add a dialog box/confirm message with 'Yes' and 'No'. If you click yes then form data submit to DB otherwise stay on the current form. I have tried to "submit Handler" but the submit Handler display "OK or "Cancel"  but if cancel selected the page get refresh which is not what I want. If the user selected "Cancel" I want to bring user back the unsubmitted page.

Any help greatly appreciated!

### Here are my codes:

```
function isValid() {
    $('#form1').validate();
    return $('#form1').valid(); 
}

$('#form1').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

}).validate({

    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
                ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below.'
                : 'You missed ' + errors + ' required fields.  They have been highlighted below.';
            if ($("#error").is(':hidden')) {
                $("#error").show();
            }
            $("#error").html(message);
            $("#error").css({
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background": "#FFCECE"
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#error").hide();
            $("error").css({
                "border": "",
                "background": ""
            });
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },

    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.attr('type') == 'radio') {
            var errorLoc = $(element).closest('.form-group').find('label:first').after(error);
            errorLoc.after(error);
        }
        else {
            $(element).after(error);
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {

        answer = confirm("Are you ready to submitted this request ? Once submitted request can not be edited!");

        if (answer == true) {
            form.submit();
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
    }
});
```

---

Comment: In your `submitHandler`, have you tried `return` instead of `event.preventDefault()`? Do you even get an `event` instance?

Comment: Yes, I tried return false and didn't work.